# Launch fragment map with address to search

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

Im having a issue I dont know how to resolve.

I have a fragment with a `editText` and a `button`.
The `button` launches a fragment map like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        //Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.SearchButton:

                Home activity = (Home) getActivity();
                if(activity != null)activity.openMapFragment();
                break;
        }
```

and the function `openMapFragment()`:

```
public void openMapFragment(){
        Fragment fragment = new gMapFragment();
        replaceFragment(fragment);
    }
```

How would i do to send the text inserted on `editText` field as a address to look for on map fragment?

Comment: hope this  will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/12739968/3790150

Comment: Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use bundle to pass data to a fragment :

```
public void openMapFragment(String args){
    Fragment fragment       = new gMapFragment();
    Bundle bundle           = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("foo", args);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    replaceFragment(fragment);
}
```

And to retrieve data :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    String foo = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString("foo") : "";
    //...
}
```

Comment: and once I do that, how would I recover the parameters on the fragment (`"foo"` in this case) ? EDIT: I already saw how. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea how to fix the NullPointerException?

Comment: fixed it. `this.getArguments().getString("foo");`  and on the activity: `fragment.setArguments(bundle);`